# Recording meeting 1 while i'm attending also meeting 2 - Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to enter in two meetings and to record only one of them in microsoft teams? For example i'd like to record meeting 1 and to attend meeting 2 without recording audio of meeting 2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: who downvotes my question is kindly asked to specify why

Answer (score -1):

@Gennaro, You can't be part of two calls. If you dial second one, first one will go on hold - which you can resume after disconnecting second one.
Probably the option is to attend one and ask someone from meeting two to record. You will receive the recording or someone from meeting can share it with you.